# Tour of heroes Search component if observable is empty

Tags: angular

I create the Tour of Heroes, and it works.

But I try to "upgrade" a part of the code and I'm not able to do it.

In the hero.service.ts code you have this part of code about the search:

```
* GET heroes whose name contains search term */

searchHeroes(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
   if (!term.trim()) {
        // if not search term, return empty hero array.
      return of([]);
   }
   return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`).pipe(
   tap(_ => this.log(`found heroes matching "${term}"`)),
   catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('searchHeroes', []))
   );
}
```

My problem is : if I search for something that doesn't exist like "gol" the message rteurned is : found heroes matching "gol"

**WRONG** I don't found heroes.

So how Can I validate if my observable is empty or not ?

I try something

```
 private hero = new Observable<Hero[]>(); 
    searchHeroes(term: string): Observable<Hero[]> {
this.hero = this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`);
 if (!term.trim()) {
      // if not search term, return empty hero array.
      return of([]); //Seulement si le champ recherche est vide, pas si le retour est vide
    }
    this.hero = this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`);


    console.log(term, this.hero, Hero.length);
    if (this.hero !=0) {
      return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`).pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`NO heroes matching "${term}"`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('searchHeroes', []))
      );
    }else{
      return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`).pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`found heroes matching "${term}"`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('searchHeroes', []))
      );
      }
  }
```

It doesn't work. So how can I manage the observable to know if it's empty or not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `http.get` *is* an observable. A totally valid one. Thus, checking the *observable* against 0, null, etc. isn't going to work as it's a valid object. What you want to do is adjust the logic in the handler for the emission from the observable.

In this case, if you want to log something different when no results are returned you would adjust your `tap` handler (`tap` is "do this as well when the observable emits") although you could also check for this in the `subscribe` handler. Something like:

```
if (!term.trim()) {
    // if not search term, return empty hero array.
  return of([]);
}
return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}/?name=${term}`).pipe(
tap(result => {
   if (result.length > 0) {
       this.log(`found heroes matching "${term}"`)
   } else {
       this.log('no matching heroes found');
   }
}),
catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('searchHeroes', []))
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks. But I made a correction to your code because was not working. line 8, replace by : this.log(`found heroes matching "${term}"`); and line 12: }), and finally line 13: catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('searchHeroes', [])));

Comment: @baronming Yeah, that's what I get for doing this without an IDE :)